# Thymeleaf expressions display in browser

Tags: java, html, thymeleaf

I have a web application that displays various data to the user using thymeleaf expressions.

```
<span th:inline="text" tabindex="-1">[[${#numbers.formatDecimal(userEditsModel.dollarAmount, 0, 'COMMA', 2, 'POINT')}]]</span>
```

And the userEditsModel is just a simple POJO:

```
public class UserEditsModel {
    private String dollarAmount;

    public String getDollarAmount() {
        return dollarAmount;
    }

    public void setDollarAmount(String dollarAmount) {
        this.dollarAmount = dollarAmount;
    }
}
```

This particular expression was displaying just fine on a lower environment. For example, something like this:

2,345.00

But now the code has been deployed to a higher environment and it is displaying the thymeleaf expression unevaluated:

[[${#numbers.formatDecimal(userEditsModel.dollarAmount, 0, 'COMMA', 2, 'POINT')}]]

If anyone has any idea what could cause this, I would be very grateful!

Comment: What is "a higher environment"?

Comment: A different environment. Different server, database, etc.

Comment: Is it the same war file in both environment?

Comment: Yes. The same war file. I can't ascertain any difference in the data ether.

Comment: At this point, I don't have any hypotheses as to what could make thymeleaf fail to process an expression.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that

```
userEditsModel.dollarAmount
```

is null.

It was very confusing at first because I have limited access to the DB, application server, etc.

As it turns out thymeleaf is printing out the whole expression if the value is null. Why isn't it throwing an exception? I don't know.